# Reducing the setpoint by 1 degree C will save 7% energy: what's the origin of that claim?

Tags: energy, heating

I often hear a claim saying that reducing the thermostat's setpoint by one degree C will reduce the overall yearly energy consumption by 7%. I've heard heating control manufacturers, energy consultants, and heating installers repeat this claim.

However I have not been able to find out where this number comes from, and indeed I suspect that this number may vary a lot from building to building.

Does anyone know where this number comes from? And how reliable it really is?

Comment: It will vary by building, by local climate, by hot water consumption, and most importantly by current setpoint temperature. I'll try to find time to write up a proper answer.

Comment: imagine a building where it is always 20C outside. If you keep your thermostat at 21 and I talk you into lowering to 20, you will save a lot more than 7%! OTOH if it's -40, I doubt the savings are so much.

Answer (score 2):

[Kate is correct](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2852/reducing-the-setpoint-by-1-degree-c-will-save-7-energy-whats-the-origin-of-th#comment3396_2852), and it is a good example.

Turn it around the other way: 7% for a 1 degree setback amounts to an average heating regime of 14 degrees C.  Multiply by 365 days a year, this corresponds to a 5100 degree day heating climate.  That's about a 9000 F degree days.  That corresponds to a very cold climate.

It's worse:  A house has to be badly designed to no solar heat to some degree.  My house, not anywhere close to R-2000 standards doesn't require us to turn on the furnace until the outside temperature is close to freezing.  In addition internal waste energy gives the house a nudge.  Lights, cooking, domestic hot water, all help warm the house.

[EnergyNumbers has another good example](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2852/reducing-the-setpoint-by-1-degree-c-will-save-7-energy-whats-the-origin-of-th#comment3395_2852).  As the climate gets closer to inside temps, the benefit of lowering the set point increases.  Since a 5100C degree day heating season is at the cold end, the claim is actually quite conservative.